# Differences between this two methods (Chapter 4 Michael Hartl Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, railstutorial.org

So I'm learning the methods and in this [part](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec-method_definitions) I found to ways of writing a method, so I tried to rewrite this:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
     return base_title
    else
      "#{page_title} | #{base_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Into this

```
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" 
    return base_title if page_title.empty? 
    return "#{page_title} | #{base_title}" 
end
```

But in this last case it gives me a lot of errors on /gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should work, what are the last errors in the stack trace?

Comment: I have no Idea what "errors in stack trace" are. The only errors that had were a syntax error from a lot of origins. The bundle exec rspec -b worked good, but I'm still trying to understand what backtrace is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first off you are looking at the wrong line in your rspec backtrace. It's where the error gets thrown in the rspec code, not what actually is causing it. You should run rspec with the -b option to get actual backtraces from your code.

Also an easier way to write this would be:

```
# assuming you pass in nil, not "", so #compact would work
def full_title(page_title = nil)
  ["Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App", page_title].compact.join(" | ")
end
```

Alternative way, so it handles blank arguments as well:

```
def full_title(page_title)
  title = ["Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"]
  title << page_title if page_title.present?
  title.join(" | ") 
end
```

As for the original issue - i think it's your inconsistent return points.

Comment: I would like to know to, I thank you for the tip on rspec -b, and for showing that are at least 4 ways of writing the same code.